# How can i show HTML code block based on if date inasp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and want to show Bootstrap Modals only if date is less than 10-03-2021 (10-March-2021)

I tried something like this

```
@{
if (DateTime.Now >= '10-03-2021')
//then show this
//HTML

}else
{
//else shows this
//HTML
}
```

Comment: Try `if (DateTime.Now >= new Date('2021-03-10'))` You're trying to compare a Date to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Converting string to `DateTime`:

```
@using System.Globalization
@{ 
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact("23/12/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), 
         DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt) 
       && DateTime.Now >= dt)   
    {
        //then show this
        //HTML    
    }
    else
    {
        //else shows this
        //HTML
    }
}
```

For more details see [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0)

*NOTE: But in case your application is processing `DateTime` from different time zone (for example date/time is saved in a database) it is recommended to convert all `DateTime` to Universal Time and after that make the comparison.*